# js getting value from html tag

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="member"><thead>
<tr>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>Gracz</th>
<th>Ludność</th>
<th>Osady</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>
    <td class="ra">1.</td><td class="pla"><a href="spieler.php?uid=5473">rafal12</a></td><td class="hab">8801</td>
    <td class="vil">12</td><td class="on"><img class="online2" src="img/x.gif" title="Logował(a) się w ciągu ostatnich 24 godzin" alt="Logował(a) się w ciągu ostatnich 24 godzin" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td class="ra">2.</td><td class="pla"><a href="spieler.php?uid=3136">rspboss</a></td><td class="hab">7131</td>
    <td class="vil">11</td><td class="on"><img class="online2" src="img/x.gif" title="Logował(a) się w ciągu ostatnich 24 godzin" alt="Logował(a) się w ciągu ostatnich 24 godzin" /></td></tr><tr>
    <td class="ra">57.</td><td class="pla"><a href="spieler.php?uid=762">zxcv</a></td><td class="hab">1670</td>
    <td class="vil">4</td><td class="on"><img class="online1" src="img/x.gif" title="teraz on-line" alt="teraz on-line" /></td></tr><tr>
.... and so on...
```

That's sample of html table that I want to collect data from. What I want to retrive are values inside img tags inside this table and make list of them. How can I get that value?

How can I say if `img class` was `online1` or `online2`?

Any help is welcome

PS: it would be great, if someone would be so nice, to guide me how to make list of them and put it into `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Find all the images that are inside the tbody of the table with the id member
oImages = document.getElementById("member").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("img");
//Create an array that will contain refrences for all the img tags
aImages = [];
//go through all of the images, check their class, and append them to
//the array if the class match
for(i-0; i<oImages.length; i++){
  if(oImages[i].className == "online1") aImages.push(oImages[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1! This is more or less what I was thinking but being spolied by jQuery, couldn't come up with it fast enough!

Comment: so without `getElementsByTagName("img");` I can access whole tag `td`, yes? but how can I treat `<tr> ... </tr>` as one? I mean... I want to make some kind of map with `"spieler.php?uid=XXXX"` as key and `online state` as value... hmmm making 2 lists - one with player names, second with `online1` and `online2` values together and mapping one list to the second should do the job...

Comment: If I understand you correctly: you could give an Id to the <tr> tag ("online1") and create another row and give it the "online2" ID to separate them, then you could use document.getElementById("online1").getElementsByTagName("img") and do the same loop (but without checking for the ID) and the same for the second list(online2).

Comment: I can't ingerate into html, anyway thanks for your ideas. I'll have to do it (my map like thing) in bad style - with 2 separate lists, but it surely will work :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check for class names by saying:

```
document.getElementById([id]).className
```

But since you don't have id on images, it becomes little difficult. Doing it pure JS way is to get the table element and loop through its children until you find the img tag.

I suggest adding an id to img tags or use a library like jQuery to make it easy.

Comment: Edited my answer a bit. Also, you can repeat the process for multiple ids. I know this isn't the exact answer he's looking for, but there's nothing wrong technically in it.

Comment: he is looking to get all the class names of the img tags .. thus getElementById wont work.. you would have to get a list of the img tags unless he wants to give each img a id

Comment: Yes, and that's what I've added.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you - that is a correct way to get the css class for a dom node.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

this script will grab all the classes for you of the image tags.. not really sure what you are looking for as far as the XMLHttpRequest but this should help you on your way

```
var imgTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var results = [];
for(var i=0;i<imgTags.length;++i)
{
    results.push(imgTags[i].className);
}
```

the results are stored in the array results;

Comment: You can make it bit more accurate by filtering only the table's img tags and not every img on the page. Also, I'm not sure if `getAttribute('class')` is cross browser compatible. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to retrieve the values of different attributes from img elements in the page.
In this case you can use the getAttribute method (see http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute) which gets the value of a certain attribute from an element.
To get the img elements you can use the getElementsByTagName method (see http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/getElementsByTagName).
Using the two methods you could iterate through all the img elments and compare their classes:

```
if(imageElement.className == 'online1')
{
 var value = imageElement.getAttribute('src'); //This will retrun the value for the source of the image
}
// The same for online2 class
```